# Regex Pattern - Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I need to create a regex - with the following requirements

starts with C, D, F, G, I, M or P
has at least one underscore (_)

eg. C6352_3

I've tried the following like this

```
@Pattern(regexp = '^(\C|\D|\F|\G|\I\|\M|\P)+\_*' , message = "error")
```

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to match a word or a whole string? If a string, try `^[CDFGIMP][^_\s]*_` or `(?s)^[CDFGIMP][^_\s]*_\S*$`

Comment: `^[CDFGIMP].*_.*$`

Comment: It would a word - one string, no spaces

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/^[CDFGIMP][^_\s]*_\S*$/
```

Or, to only handle *word* chars (letters, digits and `_`),

```
/^[CDFGIMP]\w*_\w*$/
```

or a bit more efficient one with character class subtraction:

```
/^[CDFGIMP][\w&&[^_]]*_\w*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ci1TSv/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[CDFGIMP]` - any char listed in the character set
- `[^_\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `_` and whitespace
- `\w*` - matches 0+ word chars: letters, digits or `_` (`[\w&&[^_]]*` matches 0+ letters and digits only)
- `_` - an underscore
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars (or `\w*` will match any letters, digits or `_`)
- `$` - end of string (or better, `\z` to only match at the very end of the string).

Comment: Why do you exclude `_` in `[^_\s]*`? Shouldn't `\S*` be enough for *at least one underscore*?

Comment: @sp00m That is just to speed up matching, to reduce backtracking. Compare [this one](https://regex101.com/r/LTcVBj/1) to [this one](https://regex101.com/r/LTcVBj/2).

Answer (score 1):

You could skip regex, and make it readable:

```
boolean valid(String value) {
   (value?.take(1) in ['C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'M', 'P']) && value?.contains('_')
}
```